# In pharo, it's possible to run code inside both playground and transcript. When to do each?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

In Pharo, it's usual to run code inside Playground, and using Transcript to print the output. But I noticed it's also possible to run code inside Transcript, not only printing things there. For example, if I type:

```
Transcript clear.
```

Inside the Transcript window, and run it by Ctrl+D, the window will be cleared. So my question is, when does make sense to run code inside the Transcript window instead of Playground? Is there a use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, we need to clear some things out:

You can run any code (almost) anywhere in the image. So if you open a method for example, type somewhere there `Transcript clear`, select it and hit Ctrl+D the transcript window will be cleared.

Transcript is just a "singleton" linked to a window that makes it easy to output some text and see it somewhere. It's not hard to construct a similar functionality on your own, or you can even output to a file for example. Transcript is there just for convenience during a troubleshooting activity. I would still recommend to use the debugger in a first place, but there may be situations where a debugger won't cut it.

Playground is a tool designed to "play" with your code. It's paired with an inspector, so whenever you run some code, you can inspect the resulting object in a user-friendly way. There are also some other features, like browsing variable bindings or storing code snippets, or browsing the playground code history. As I mentioned before you can run any code anywhere, but Playground is optimized for trying out stuff.

Answer (score 4):

### Some differences between Transcript and Playground

1. You can refer to the `Transcript` from anywhere to print on it. You cannot do the same with Playgrounds.
2. Since the `Transcript` is global, your script is exposed to getting dirty or cleared. In fact, there are many methods that print warning messages and the like on the `Transcript`. You can find them by searching its References.
3. Temporaries are automatically created in Playgrounds. You have to explicitly declare them in your `Transcript` scripts.
4. In some dialects of Smalltalk (not in Pharo), closing the `Transcript` will close the system. Playgrounds (a.k.a. Workspaces) can be freely open and closed in all dialects.
5. There is a Find command in the `Transcript` (guess why.)
6. The `Transcript` is a `WriteStream`: it responds to `#nextPutAll:`, `#flush`, etc. You can use it to test code intended to dump contents on any stream-like object (e.g., files).

---

And important consequence of 3 above is that you can store the result(s) of your evaluation in Playground temporaries. These will remain available until you close the Playground. In the `Transcript`, instead, the value of any temporary will only last while your code is being evaluated so you will have no chance but to print your result for it to remain visible, which is much more limited than the Playground behavior, where you can come back later and inspect or keep using your result objects for further experimentation.

---

In my opinion, it is not a good idea to use the Playground for non-trivial scripts. It is much better to create a class and put some methods in it. To try your code use Unit Tests (again classes and methods). That way the code would be organized, searchable, classifiable, etc., and your "scripts" would become so short that you won't need any Playground.

---

The `Transcript` should have two areas. One for *output* and another for *input*. The output area would display the messages, annotations and results produced by `Transcript show: <whatever>` and `Transcript nextPutAll: <string>`. The input area should be equivalent to a simplified Playground, so to save you the task of opening a Playground for evaluating short code snippets that you will soon discard.

Comment: In Pharo 9 there is some work going on allowing you to refer to other playgrounds and the bindings defined there